# Angular2 and deploy

Tags: angular, deployment

What is your practice to deploy your angular2 project with typescript into a server?

Now I copy my builded files on the server, but may be I can do it in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy my Angular project to my production server, I compile it using Angular-Cli using the production and the AOT flags.

```
$ ng build --prod --aot
```

Then I copy the contents of the `dist/` folder to my Apache folder. To make sure that the routing is handled correctly, I have written a `.htaccess` file that configures Apache to handle the routing appropriately.
In practice, this is all done by a Jenkins script.